# Choosing max of date from duplicates

Tags: sql

Suppose we have multiple records of the following form:

`A B C  date1

  A B C  date 2
 D E F  date3

  D E F  date 4`

I want to only select the distinct records where the date is the largest. So if  `date2`  is the largest, chose that  `ABC`  record. Similarly, if  `date3`  is the largest, choose that  `DEF`  record.

Comment: Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: What database are you using? What are the table and column names? What have you tried to get the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: What have you tried..? Is this file data or table data..

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably something like this;

```
SELECT A, B, C, Date
FROM table t1
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.A = t1.A AND t2.B = t1.B AND t2.C = t1.C)
```

Cleaner would be to make a CTE (or subquery), to get the max date for each combination of other columns, then join back to that from the table